# Rewriting a URL containing a path with a number

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a URL:

```
apple.com/news/0/3473/page/
```

How can I rewrite or mask it so that it looks like:

```
apple.com/news/0/page/
```

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]|[0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://apple.com/news/$1/$3 [R=301,L]
```

and it successfully removes the undesired number, but it seems to forward rather than mask te URL, and the original URL is needed by the content management system.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what mod_rewrite does. Its purpose is to rewrite URLs so that the *server* can process them appropriately; if you want to change only what the *client* sees then you'll need to use JavaScript instead.